# Convert Julian Date to Normal Date in Node.js for IBM DB2 iSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2, apigee

In one of my application development I am using IBM DB2 iSeries database connected with DataDirect technology given by Progress with db2.jar. In database the date stored as 7 digit Julian format that I have to convert in normal date as timestamp in Node.js as my data layer has been implemented in Node.js that has to deploy on Apigee. 
I need a generic solution that can convert this julian date to normal date at SQL query level as well as in Node.js

Example of Julian date is 1160920 this is corresponds to 2016-09-20.

Comment: Did you try to google it first? There's many answers here on StackOverflow, just use search.

Comment: Whatever you mean by "Julian date", 1160920 cannot possibly correspond to 20 Sept. 2016 in the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: That's not a Julian date, it's a regular date stored with only 7 digits as CYYMMDD.

Answer (score 4):

After much investigation I come with a solution for both at SQL level as well as node.js level.

To convert 7 digit Julian date into Normal Date using SQL query you can use below query for IBM DB2 iSeries database -

```
SELECT DATE(((1160920 /10000)+1900)|| '-' ||
(MOD(1160920 ,10000) /100)|| '-' ||
MOD(1160920 ,100))
FROM
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

To perform same conversion using node.js use below code it will convert perfectly

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
function julianIntToDate(n) {

    var yy = ((n/10000)+1900);
    var year = Math.floor(yy);
    var mm = ((n % 10000)/100);
    var mon = Math.floor(mm);
    mon = leadingZero(mon);
    var dd = (n % 100);
    dd = leadingZero(dd);
    console.log("Year--"+year);
    console.log("Month--"+mon);
    console.log("Day--"+dd);

    var now = new Date(year+"-"+mon+"-"+dd);
    console.log("Converted Date-->"+now);
    orderDate = dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-0500");
    return (orderDate);

    function leadingZero(value) {
    if (value < 10) {
    return "0" + value.toString();
    }
    return value.toString();
    }
}
console.log("Julian Date--->"+1160920);
console.log("Normal Date--->"+julianIntToDate(1160920).toString());
```